# Ubuntu login screen won't let me log in

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-mate

I'm a windows user (hopefully not soon), and I'm really unexperienced with linux right now. I just installed ubuntu-mate 16.04 on a separate internal hdd.

When I enter recovery mode and use the root shell and enter `startx`, I get a few errors.

```
Fatal server error: could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock
Giving up
Unable to connect to x server: connecton refused
Server errr
Error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
[DEPEND] dependency failed for cryptography setup for cryptswap1
" dependency failed for encrypted volumes
Dependency failed for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device
Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
Dependency failed for swap
```

Those are the errors I get with `startx`.

When I log in normally, (fixed an issue where my password was always incorrect) and I put in the password, the screen goes black, flickers text all over the place and random colors like I've seen during boot, then goes back to the login screen.

Please help me if possible.

Thank you all!

Comment: Possibly related to [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: It looks like Xauthority doesn't exist...

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` ?

Comment: Also, do you know what kind of graphics card your computer has?

Comment: Alright. I can't get gdm because it wants me to apt-get update and for some reason it can't access the downloads. Also, after restarting lightdm, it won't start.

Comment: Yes, I tried to reconfigure it. AMD Radeon R7 250 series. Driver version: 16.150.0.0

Comment: I reinstalled it and when I put in the code to unencrypt the hard drive it says *ERROR* failed to set mode on [CRTC:33] *ERROR* unable to allocate a PPLL

Comment: Do you have a dual-monitor setup, by any chance? (I'm looking at this bug related to your error message: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1124328 )

Comment: Alright. Now I am able to log in, but the first password you need to boot is almost always wrong. And yes, I am trying to use 3 monitors all different sizes; acer hdmi, acer vga, hp dvi

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ubuntu seems to have fixed my problems. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @andrew.46 This is an answer by the OP.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ooops....